# Ошибка с malloc/free pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c, указатели, malloc, realloc

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста разобраться с памятью. При вызове этой функции вылетает ошибка : "17_final(10369,0x100085000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff5fbff550: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug"
Я не совсем понимаю почему, ибо я сам в этой же функции выделил память ей через malloc, а ошибка говорит о том, что память не инициализирована. Буду рад любому совету

UPDATE:
Сейчас при realloc вылетает ошибка такого рода : pointer being realloc'd was not allocated.

```
int execute(person* person_array)
{
string* parsed_command;
if(!(parsed_command = malloc(sizeof(string)))){
    error_notification(12);
    return 2;
}
parsed_command[0] = malloc(SIZE_ARG*sizeof(char));
char command[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
string quit = "quit\n";
do{
    printf("esp> ");
    if(fgets(command, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, stdin)==NULL){  // save input in "command"
        return 2;
    }
    parse_command_input(command, person_array, &parsed_command);
}while(strcmp(command,quit));
printf("Bye.\n");
free(&parsed_command[0]);
free(parsed_command);
return 0;
}




void parse_command_input(const string command, person* person_array, char*** parsed_command){
string delim = strtok(command, " ");
int counter = 0;
while (delim != NULL){
    if(counter > 0) {
        //*(parsed_command) = (string*)realloc(parsed_command, counter+2);
        char **tmp = realloc(*parsed_command, (counter+1)*sizeof(char*));
        if(tmp!=NULL)
            *parsed_command = tmp;
    }
    parsed_command[counter] = &delim;
    counter++;
    delim = strtok (NULL, " \n");
}
which_command(parsed_command, counter, person_array);
}
```

Comment: Вы можете гарантировать, что в `parse_command_input` у вас не меняется значение, на которое указывает `parsed_command`? А вообще, у вас как-то все сделано так странно, что...Зачем, например, эти игры с косвенностью `char**`, зачем выделение динамически - неужели `SIZE_ARG` настолько велико? Почему не читать сразу через `fgets`? Словом, вопросов больше, чем ответов...

Comment: Да, еще - вы потенциально можете выскочить за буфер при считывании `MAX_BUFFER_SIZE` символов и уж точно читаете за этими пределами при `i==0` в цикле...

Comment: Функция fgets() запрещена к использованию ... А динамическое выделение наоборот обязательно к исполнению

Comment: Кем запрещена? Если преподом - так вы же все равно ее используете... А динамическое выделение - ладно, но зачем двойное?

Comment: Прошу прощения, перепутал, getline() запрещена, fgets() разрешена. А на счёт той порнографии которая там написана, она сделана для обработки EOF и завершения программы, когда я пытался ввести EOF без getchar() и проверки на EOF, получался бесконечный цикл, короче не сохраняет getline() -  EOF в строку, и тогда не понятно, то ли была введена пустая строка, толи EOF, а мне при EOF надо выйти из цикла. Более изящного решения не придумал
А как сделать иначе, мне надо каждое слово введённой команды сохранить отдельно, через одномерный массив же явно не получится

Comment: Проверять, что возвращает fgets...

Comment: @Harry, действительно, нашёл способ, спасибо за совет, не судите строго, только учусь :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эта ошибка может быть связана с тем, что в вашей программе где-то происходит запись за пределы выделенной памяти, в результате чего значение указателя `parsed_command` было перезаписано. То есть ваша программа имеет неопределенное поведение.

Проверьте все функции и циклы, где вы используете переменные `command` и `parsed_command`.

Самый простой способ - это вставить вывод на консоль значения переменной `parsed_command` везде после того, как она была использована.

Например,

```
printf( "%p\n", ( void * )parsed_command[0] );
```

Попутно замечу, что уже данный цикл не корректный

```
    for(int i = MAX_BUFFER_SIZE-1; i>=0; i--) {
        command[i]=command[i-1];
                           ^^^^
    }
```

так как когда переменная `i` равна `0`, то происходит обращение к памяти за пределами массива.

**EDIT** Судя по комментарию к моему ответу, возможно, что причиной неопределенного поведения программы могло стать перераспределение памяти, адресуемой указателем `parsed_command`, когда указатель был передан в функцию по значению. Например,

```
void f( char **p );
{
    p = realloc( p, 2 * sizeof( char * ) );
    //...
}

//...

f( parsed_command );
```

В этом случае исходный указатель `parsed_command` не был изменен. Функция имела дело с копией исходного указателя. В результате вы можете получить ошибку при освобождении указателя `parsed_command` , говорящую о том, что память уже была освобождена. Если это имеет место, то надо передавать указатель в функцию по ссылке. Например,

```
void f( char ***p );
             ^^^
{
    char **tmp = realloc( *p, 2 * sizeof( char * ) );

    if ( tmp != NULL ) *p = tmp;
    //...
}

//...

f( &parsed_command );
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Спасибо, поправил массив, теперь ошибка вылетает на втором free() а первый работает

Comment: @AntonBarinov Распечатайте указатель printf( "%p\n", ( void * )parsed_command ); после выделения памяти и перед удалением и сравните полученные значения. Если они отличаются. то ищите то место в программе, где они изменяются.

Comment: Посмотрел в дебаггере, и в момент инициализации и в момент вызова функции free() адрес одинаковый. Прошёлся по программе шаг за шагом в случае при одном введённом аргументе и при нескольких ( тогда будет работать realloc из другой ф-ии, добавил её в листинг ) и адрес не изменяется от самого начала до конца, при этом всё равно ошибка pointer being freed was not allocated для free(parsed_command);

Comment: @AntonBarinov   Я могу лишь гадать, но подозреваю, что вы передали этот указатель по значению (то есть передали в функцию копию значения указател) в функцию, где вызвали realloc для этой копии. В результате исходный указатель у вас не изменился. Изменилось лишь значение параметра функции, который является локальной переменной функции. После выхода из функции этот параметр прекратил свое существование. Вам надо передавать исходный указатель по ссылке.

Comment: Ну это же можно проверить распечатав содержимое переменной перед освобождением памяти, если она будет пустой, то значит я работал с копией, а если в ней будет то, что и должно по хожу программы, значит через ссылку передавалась она?

Comment: @AntonBarinov У вас не изменится значение указателя. Тем не менее память была освобождена, когда некая функция работала с копией указателя благодаря вызову realloc.

Comment: Да, действительно, везде копия, надо всё поменять, в любом случае огромное спасибо за ответ и помощь !

Comment: @AntonBarinov Не за что. Спрашивайте еще.:)

Comment: Тогда пожалуй спрошу, в дополнительной функции, в которой я получаю parsed_command через ***, правильно ли будет делать расширение массива таким способом (добавил в листинг )

Comment: @AntonBarinov Почему вы приводите к типу char? Я показал в своем ответе, как надо в функции перераспределять память.

Comment: Да, что то я совсем плыву, просмотрел, спасибо

Comment: Сделал всё как в шаблоне, но теперь вылетает ошибка по поводу realloc, добавил в листинг

Comment: @AntonBarinov Не надо постоянно корректировать свой вопрос. Это будет вводить в заблуждение тех, кто будет читать вопрос и ответ. Задайте новый вопрос, если у вас возникает новая проблема.

Comment: да, вы правы, спасибо