# pointer being realloc'd was not allocated. ошибка памяти си

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста разобраться с памятью. При вызове realloc функции parse_command_input вылетает ошибка : "pointer being realloc'd was not allocated."

В чём может быть проблема?

```
typedef char* string;

int execute(person* person_array)
{
string* parsed_command;
if(!(parsed_command = malloc(sizeof(string)))){
    error_notification(12);
    return 2;
}
parsed_command[0] = malloc(SIZE_ARG*sizeof(char));
char command[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
string quit = "quit\n";
do{
    printf("esp> ");
    if(fgets(command, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, stdin)==NULL){  // save input in "command"
        return 2;
    }
    parse_command_input(command, person_array, &parsed_command);
}while(strcmp(command,quit));
printf("Bye.\n");
free(&parsed_command[0]);
free(parsed_command);
return 0;
}




void parse_command_input(const string command, person* person_array, char*** parsed_command){
string delim = strtok(command, " ");
int counter = 0;
while (delim != NULL){
    if(counter > 0) {
        char **tmp = realloc(*parsed_command, (counter+1)*sizeof(char*));
        if(tmp!=NULL)
            *parsed_command = tmp;
    }
    parsed_command[counter] = &delim;
    counter++;
    delim = strtok (NULL, " \n");
}
which_command(parsed_command, counter, person_array);
}
```

Comment: А что такое у вас `string`?

Comment: там typedef char* string

Comment: @Anton Barinov: Начните с того, что прекратите заводить typedef-имена, за которыми скрываются указатели. Совершенно непонятно, какого уровня у вас в коде указатель получается.

Comment: И в чем **принципиальное** отличие этого вопроса от http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604984/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81-malloc-free-pointer-being-freed-was-not-allocated ?

Answer (score 1):

Код не имеет смысла.
Например, зачем здесь выделяется память?

```
string* parsed_command;
if(!(parsed_command = malloc(sizeof(string)))){
    error_notification(12);
    return 2;
}
parsed_command[0] = malloc(SIZE_ARG*sizeof(char));
```

Где используется этот массив длинною `SIZE_ARG`?

Почему в этом предложении берется адрес указателя?

```
free(&parsed_command[0]);
    ^^^
```

Указатель `parsed_command` вообще не используется  функции `execute`. Поэтому совершенно не ясно, почему он в ней объявлен.

Какой смысл в этом предложении?

```
parsed_command[counter] = &delim;
```

Здесь происходит обращение к не выделенной памяти.

Comment: Суть в том что мне нужен динамический массив в котором будет сохраняться вводимая команда в виде каждого отдельного слова в своей ячейке. В последствии это обрабатывается и вызываются различные команды ( их 6 ). Поэтому и выделяю память динамически, и с каждым новым вводимым словом мне надо её расширить. Я делю введённую команды на слова по пробелам, сохраняю эти слова по отдельности в delim, потос расширяю память и сохраняю delim в parsed_command. Вот такой смысл.  На счёт free(), там ошибка, поправил.

Comment: как вы думаете, может быть было бы лучше и инициализировать и освобождать после каждого вызова сразу этот массив прямо в parsed_input_command() , потому что как я понимаю, я каждый раз расширяю память, при каждом вызове, а смысла в этом нет, один вред, лучше освободить её после вызова?

Comment: И прошу прощения за оффтоп, но у вас явно много опыта в программирование, не могли бы вы подсказать какую либо книгу(можно на английском/немецком), или что то тому подобное, где подробно описана работа с потоками/многопоточностью на си, сколько не искал, везде либо урывками либо лишь часть информации, в университете тоже лишь дают ссылки на сайт с кратким описанием. Заранее спасибо

Comment: @AntonBarinov Увы, я не знаю ни одной книги про многопоточность на C.

Comment: а как её тогда узнать/выучить? где взять информацию? исключительно форумы и статьи?

Comment: @AntonBarinov При помощи поиска в интернет.